# Hide Launcher Bar for All Users

Tags: 12.10

I tried hiding my launcher bar on my local account, but when I go to other users on the active directory, it is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Every user has his own settings. You need to configure each user independently. ... Just login to each user and set the launcher to be hidden for them all one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Mina: The users have not logged in yet, and any user from the active directory could log into the machine... so it would be impossible to configure each user independently.